# Charge decay (leakage) of a charged metallic sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance

I have a spherical ball (charged to a specific charge) and the charge on the ball leaks to the surrounding. I observe that the charge on the ball reduces exponentially. Can anyone give a theoretical model (a simple one) explaining the phenomenon?

Answer (score 3):

Use Ohm's Law, charge conservation law and Gauss's Theorem

$\vec j=\sigma \vec E$,

$I =-\frac {dQ}{dt}$,

$I=\int \vec {j}.\vec {dS}=\int \sigma \vec E.\vec {dS}=\sigma Q/\epsilon$

Consequently $\frac{dQ}{dt}=-\frac {\sigma Q}{\epsilon}$ and $Q=Q_0\exp (-\sigma t/\epsilon)$,

$\sigma $ is electrical conductivity, and $\epsilon$ is the dielectric constant.

Answer (score 2):

Your ball is acting as one pole of a capacitor; the other pole is 'the surrounding". There's a finite resistance (non-zero obviously) between the two as well.

So the simple theoretical model is what's called an RC circuit; it's just a resistor and a capacitor connected in parallel.

If by "rate" you mean what fraction of the charge is lost per second, then no, it doesn't depend on the initial charge.

[Wikipedia's page on capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance#Self-capacitance) is a good place to start.

Comment: That is the model that I had as well, but I have no idea how to get the resistance. Is it something that needs to be found experimentally or is there any theoretical way of expressing in terms of fundamental constants

Comment: You could put together an estimate based on [the resistivity of air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_and_conductivity_of_various_materials). And that would indeed be useful, but it would be quite approximate because, geometry aside, the humidity will vary and will affect your observed figure.

Comment: How do I conclude that  the resistance that I am supposed to use is finite?

Comment: Are you observing the voltage of the ball decreasing over time? If you are, then either the _conductance_ between the ball and everything else is greater than zero, or the capacitance is increasing (which is possible, if for example the ball were blowing up like a balloon or your lab-mate were inching a metal pen closer to it while you weren't looking, but unlikely).